# Failed to enable constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null)

I The load event i wrote this code:

```
private DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();
private SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
ds1.Clear();
da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Département, division,Sérvice where Département.Num_Département = Division.Num_Département_Département and Sérvice.Num_Division_Division = Division.Num_Division", sql.cn);
da1.Fill(ds1, "Sérvice");
da1.Fill(ds1, "Division");
da1.Fill(ds1, "Département");
```

but when i run the form it gives me this error :

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

What am I have to do ?

Comment: The first think i thought about are the wierd letters <é> in all names, i would feel much better if i would eliminate these

Comment: but this requet works fine in SQL-Server.
I have in another form the same requet and it works, but when i fill a dataTable.

Comment: try to run it usign a simple select with table like only "select * from Département" and da1.Fill(ds1, "Division"); does it work?

Comment: no .. the same problem .. i think because i have a row that contins a NULL value