# Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. MyDataset.Tables[0].Merge

Tags: c#

When i'm trying to merge Table in dataset this Exception Occurred :-
(Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.)

Code:

```
MyDataset.Tables[0].Merge(dt, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```

Comment: Do you have a question? The exception is self-explanatory.

Comment: trying to add Table in dataset ? Try `MyDataset.Tables.Add(dt);` Hope it would do what you are trying...... :)

Comment: Have a look at [Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null).

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the question in Murat Yıldız comment, but none of the answers worked with my setup. My code failed at the `Merge` method too. What worked in my case was this snippet, taken from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/405938/Debugging-DataSet-Constraint-Errors

```
try
{
    dataSet.Merge(anotherDataSet);
}
catch (ConstraintException)
{
    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        DataRow[] rowErrors = table.GetErrors();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(table.TableName + " Errors:" + rowErrors.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowErrors.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rowErrors[i].RowError);

            foreach (DataColumn col in rowErrors[i].GetColumnsInError())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(col.ColumnName + ":" + rowErrors[i].GetColumnError(col));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx alot. This is the best way to get the actual Error. In my case it says "Failed to enable .... foreign-key constraints .... "

but table.GetErrors() shows that the actual reason is maxLength of the column was exeeded.