# ASP.NET Stored procedure error

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure which returns "Tabular data" and have only "Get method".

I unchecked "Fill a DataTable" checkbox. And Method name is empty field.

So, i only have a Get method to get rows from database table.

SQL code works fine when i tried it in SQL management studio.

But when i create a stored procedure, i get an alert:

[image]
I use BLL/BO/DAL architecture

I call my stored procedure like:

```
MyDataTable dt = myAdapter.MyStoredProcedure();
```

And the i get an error:

"System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints"

[image]

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check this same issues

[Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1258783.aspx/2/10