# InnerJoin Query giving "Failed to enable constraints" error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have this query running against 2008R2. `tblJoin` is the table in between two tables(`tblIncident` and `tblPatron`) for many-to-many relationship.

While I am building the query in VS2012, in the Query Builder window when I execute the query it runs fine and gives me the desired results. However in the last step when I click on TestQuery and enter the parameter it gives an error:

```
"Failed to enable constraints.."
```

I checked the datatype and they all match against each other against the tables,

```
SELECT tblIncident.Inci_ID, 
 _tblJoin.PatronID, 
 _tblJoin.LName, 
 _tblJoin.FName, 
 _tblJoin.MI
FROM tblJoin INNER JOIN
    tblIncident ON tblJoin.InciID = tblIncident.Inci_ID AND tblJoin.InciID = tblIncident.Inci_ID
WHERE (tblIncident.Inci_ID = @Inci_ID)
```

Comment: what is the full error? can you show me that?

Answer (score 0):

> You need Check all the MaxLength property of the columns in your DataTable.
>
> The column that I changed from "nvarchar(512)" to "nvarchar(MAX)" still had the 512 value on the MaxLength property so I changed to "-1" and it works!!.

You can solve this issue from this discussion

[Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null)

There have many answers ....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ramesh and Vignesh. Vignesh's comment made me think about the duplicate foreign key. So I kept the query but removed the foreign key (Incident ID), that made it worked. This is how my query looks like:

```
SELECT tblJoin.PatronID, tblJoin.LName, tblJoin.FName, tblJoin.MI FROM tblJoin 
INNER JOIN tblIncident ON tblJoin.InciID = tblIncident.Inci_ID 
WHERE (tblIncident.Inci_ID = @Inci_ID)
```