# Enforcing composite primary key on existing data in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `datatable` with data. I want to add `composite primary key` to this table (say on 2 columns) and check if any row in the datatable validates the composite primary key we set.
What I have done is I have added composite primary key to the datatable

```
DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[2];
keys[0] = dt.Columns["EmpId"];
keys[1] = dt.Columns["EmpName"];
dt.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

But I am not able to figure out how to check existing data and set RowError of respective rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

**1> For setting Row Errors**

```
private void SetRowErrors(DataTable table)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        table.Rows[i].RowError = "ERROR: " 
            + table.Rows[i][1];
    }
    DataSet dataSet = table.DataSet;
    TestForErrors(dataSet);
}

private void TestForErrors(DataSet dataSet)
{
    if(dataSet.HasErrors)
    {
        foreach(DataTable tempDataTable in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            if(tempDataTable.HasErrors) 
                PrintRowErrors(tempDataTable);
        }
        dataGrid1.Refresh();
    }
}

private void PrintRowErrors(DataTable table)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if(row.HasErrors) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row.RowError);
        }
    }
}
```

**2>Check existing data for composite key violation:** Refer the link shared below

[Check existing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null)

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to check existing data for composite key violation.

Comment: @parixit- i have updated my answer for checking existing data for icomposite key violation refer it.If you are satisfied with answer don't forget to vote up and to mark as an answer.