# How to set datasource of sub report in crystal report for master detail table

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

[image]

I've these two tables, I want to generate a crystal report in which I've a sub report listing all the orders by store. But I'm having problem setting data source of sub report.

```
ReportsDataSetTableAdapters.StoreTableAdapter adp = new ReportsDataSetTableAdapters.StoreTableAdapter();
MainOrderReport report = new MainOrderReport();
ReportsDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter del = new ReportsDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter();
report.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(del.GetData().DefaultView);
report.SetDataSource(adp.GetData().DefaultView);
crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = report;
crystalReportViewer.Refresh();
```

But this code is throwing this exception:
"Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique or foreign-key constraints". 
Kindly help me, what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your given `DataSet` image, your `OrderDataTable` is child of `StoreDataTable`. While in your code you are filling your child first and parent later. And in your `DataSet` you have defined a constraint between the two tables.

Probably this is the reason why you are getting this error. Try filling the parent Table first, then child Table.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the connection first:

```
report.Subreports[0].DataSourceConnections.Clear();
report.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(adp.GetData().DefaultView);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: I'm still getting this exception, " Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique or foreign-key constraints

Comment: @Desire Okidoke, then follow the answer on this SO post to investigate your error a bit more... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null