# Why result of a query is OK in sql-server run, but has an error when I use it in a ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a Table with GUID date type field as Primery Key. when I run the query in DataSet window of ASP.net, the result is OK, but when I use it in ASP.Net Page it will return an error page like below :

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null,unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

The query has not any type of join, and a simple SUM query that add up daily work amounts in a filed based on date range which pass as a parameter to the query and Group by activities that exist in another filed.

This is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DailyReport] (
    [ReportDate]       DATETIME         NULL,
    [ReportId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ConstructionType] NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Zone]             NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [BuildingName]     NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [ActivityId]       INT              NULL,
    [TodayWork]        REAL             NULL,
    [Decription]       NTEXT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReportId] ASC)
);
```

And this is the query :

```
SELECT SUM(TodayWork) AS SumWork, ActivityId, COUNT(ReportId) AS RecordCount
FROM   DailyReport
WHERE  (ConstructionType = N'1') AND (ReportDate >= @DateStart) AND 
       (ReportDate <= @DateFinish)
GROUP BY ActivityId
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null#7029713

Comment: @RobJohnston if that's indeed a duplicate, it means the OP is trying to load data into a DataTable with incompatible constraints. We *really* need to see the code, especially if there are any non-nullable DataColumn fields in the datatable, or if there are FK constraints

Comment: I think, the problem is related to GUID Filed... my problems starts after I use GUID  instead of int primery key...

Answer (score -2):

Normally in c# int does not allow null values but that can do in sqlserver, that mean null values can be allowed by sql server but not in c#.

so it can be solved in 2 ways 
  1) either use allow null to false in database
  2) or use nullable int type in c# code by using like "int? a=null"

Comment: The OP is reading from the database, not writing to it. A @RobJohnston commented, the OP most likely is trying to load data into a DataTable with incompatible constraints