# c# and sql server 2012 date format

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, date

my date format in sql server is yyyy/MM/dd
[image]

and when I check the table data on c# the date format is MM/dd/yyyy
[image]

and when i run the code, i always encounter this error.
[image]

but when i set the value for BirthDate to NULL, the program runs smoothly.
help please.

Comment: is you changed something in `table` OR `SP` during that time

Comment: [Sql server does not store date with display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time) neither does c#. check the dataset design.

Comment: The error message doesn't state specifically that the problem is date formats. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7029713/2091410) for more information about the `ConstraintException`.