# TableAdapter exception with joins

Tags: c#, sql-server, tableadapter

I build asp.net application, for db i use TableAdapter. 
Select Query

```
SELECT
    U.empID,
    U.firstName,
    U.lastName,
    R.name AS Role
FROM
    USER_T AS U
INNER JOIN USER_ROLES_T AS UR ON U.empID = UR.empID
INNER JOIN ROLES_T AS R ON UR.roleID = R.typeID
```

`empId` with constraint `primary key`. Employee has many role attributes, it named role.

When I perform request for user data from db:

```
UsersTableAdapter usersTableAdapter = new UsersTableAdapter();
DataBase.UsersDataTable users = usersTableAdapter.GetUsers();
```

I get following exception:

> Controllers.UI.Login.LoginController|System.Data.ConstraintException:
>   Failed to
>
> enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating
>   non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

If I perform request select-request with any admin program it get

```
    28 Roman Ivanov Admin
    28 Roman Ivanov Developer
```

I understand, this happens because of `primary key empId`, how can this problem get solved? How can i remove a primary key from adapter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null)

Comment: as a sum of, what would be the result you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

open `UsersTableAdapter` design in visual studio like above image  and right click on it and delete key then save , it will work perfectly.

Comment: But i cant do it, primary key is in the database of the customer, and i dont have any options to perform remove

Comment: no no it will not drop primary key from Database it will only drop from adapter