# ASP.NET datatable: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign key constraints using MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, datatable

attempting to run a very simple query and fill a datatable, but keep getting a "Failed to enable constraints..." error (using mysql ver 8.0.13).
Here's the relevant code:

```
dim dt as new datatable
Using mycon As New MySqlConnection(...)
            Using mycmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * from output_type where 
              is_active='Y';", mycon)
            Try
                mycon.Open()
                   using myread as mysqldatareader = mycmd.executereader
                     dt.load(myread)
                   end using
                mycon.Close()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            Finally
                If mycon.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    mycon.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
return dt
```

I am absolutely certain there are no null values, foreign keys, etc in the output_type table...it is only 9 rows!! What could be causing the error.

Thanks for the help,
Daniel

Comment: Please add to your post with your table schema

Comment: We need more information as @RyanWilson suggested.  But, your error implies that there is a pre-existing foreign key constraint between the table `output_type` and another table that requirements hasn't been met.

Comment: On which line does the error appear? You could remove the empty catch statement since you are already implementing Using

Comment: Here's the schema for the table:

Comment: intake_index int(3) NO PRI  auto_increment
intake_type varchar(200) NO   
is_active char(1) YES  Y

Comment: There is no foreign key constraint anywhere for this table. It's just a simple "pick-list" table used to fill a dropdownlist. There are no nulls, no foreign key constraints, no-joins. Baffling!

Comment: I have resolved the error with the following code, but I consider it a bit of a hack and would rather fix the underlying cause with the datatable. Code in next comment:

Comment: Using dt As New DataTable
                        Dim myread As MySqlDataReader = mycmd.ExecuteReader
                        Using ds As New DataSet
                            ds.EnforceConstraints = False
                            ds.Tables.Add(dt)
                            dt.Load(myread, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)
                            ds.Tables.Remove(dt)
                        End Using
                        mycon.Close()
                        Return dt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026566/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null)